# API services doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build a service which selects all the city names from the DB according to an input from a user.

I'm trying so send the request via Postman, but I get "couldn't get any response" , and I don't know why.

My API controller:

```
[Route("city/{cityName}")]
public class CityController : Controller
{
    private ILogger<CityController> _logger;
    private IZipcodeRepository _repository;

    public CityController(ILogger<CityController> logger, IZipcodeRepository repository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult GetCities(string cityName)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //    var results = _repository.GetCitiesByCityName(cityName);
        //    return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CityViewModel>>(results));
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    _logger.LogError($"Failed to get cities: {ex}");
        //    return BadRequest("Error occured");
        //}
        return new JsonResult(new List<object>()
        {
            new { id = 1, Name ="asd"},
            new { id = 2, Name ="dsa"}
        });
```

As you can see, I marked the part of the code, to test if it is the problem, but even returning a normal JsonResult doesn't work.

In Postman, I'm using this link: http://***/city/tel

If any additional information is needed, please comment and I'll add it.

Comment: It might be your DI. Try adding a parameterless constructor, if that works then one of your constructor argument types is not properly registered. Also I am not sure why that link would work, seems like it should be "city/[cityname]". Finally the Route should be on the method, not the class. I believe you can use RoutePrefix on class (if core is the same as version 2.2)

Comment: Your route URL is incorrect, you said you are passing for method you mentioned.

Comment: I tried changing it to `city/[cityname]` , also tried to mark my constructor and replace it with a parameterless constructor , still getting the same error. Question , why shouldn't the root be on the class? if I have many method that all share the same root? Anyway , I also tried placing it above `[HttpGet()]` , it still didn't work. @Igor

Comment: @sagi You are using zipcode and tel. http://***/zipcode/tel. Are you capturing them anywhere in your api call

Comment: Do you mean the `MapRoute` on startup? `"{controller}/{action}/{id?}` ? @Amit

Comment: I mean if you are passing zipcode and tel, there should be variable defined in route somewhere to capture that

Comment: That's a typo , I'm using `http://***/city/tel` , as the route. Shouldn't I ? @Amit

Comment: Have you tried returning something other than anonymous objects in the JsonResult? I recall having a problem with that a while back. The serializer just did not like anonymous objects.

Comment: @juunas Even the template of an API application doesn't work for me :S I tried building a new project, and use the default controller they're offering them and the result is the same. I suspect its some settings or preferences or something . Any thoughts?

Comment: Remove the `Route` attribute from the class and change the `[HttpGet("")]` to `[HttpGet("city/{cityName}")]` on the method. Also, what exactly does postman tell you? What response does your server send? What do your application logs say?

Comment: @poke Read my last comment , already tried moving the route in 5 different variations , doesn't seems to be it .

Comment: Hello, its a long shot, although worth asking :-) do you have fiddler or Charles turned on running in the background to accept https and forgot to add a local cert? And or proxy turned on.. Sometimes these useful tools comenin the way

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Router on the ActionResult instead of on the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have parameter name {cityname} at the controller level route it needs to be mapped at action level. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) how it's supposed to work:

> To make attribute routing less repetitive, route attributes on the controller are combined with route attributes on the individual actions. Any route templates defined on the controller are prepended to route templates on the actions. Placing a route attribute on the controller makes all actions in the controller use attribute routing.

```
C#

[Route("products")]
public class ProductsApiController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult ListProducts() { ... }

   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public ActionResult GetProduct(int id) { ... }
}
```

In this example the URL path /products can match ProductsApi.ListProducts, and the URL path /products/5 can match ProductsApi.GetProduct(int). Both of these actions only match HTTP GET because they are decorated with the HttpGetAttribute.
Route templates applied to an action that begin with a / do not get combined with route templates applied to the controller. This example matches a set of URL paths similar to the default route.+

Comment: Make sense, but I already tried removing the route completly , partially , some in the route and some in the Http , nothing works.

Comment: Even the template of an API application doesn't work for me :S I tried building a new project, and use the default controller they're offering them and the result is the same. I suspect its some settings or preferences or something

Comment: Did you try debugging it by running it from visual studio and sending the request to local host?